# VBA excel FIND formula isse

Tags: excel, vba, find, formula

I'm trying to use the formula `FIND` in order to search for the position of the first character `@` from the text on my cell `A1` as: `FIND("@";A1)` using the following the code:

```
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR
    cel = "A" & i
    Range("Q" & i).Formula = "=FIND(" & "@" & "," & cel & ")"

Next i
```

Any help to solve the problem of my code is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Instr() function to directly write searched character position:

```
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("Q" & i).Value = Instr(Range("A" & i).Value2, "@")
Next
```